# mixed ancova or difference scores?

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, ancova

I am puzzled with how I should analyze the following data:

The dependent variable is respiratory sinus arrhythmia, a measure of parasympathetic activity (RSA). I have a $5\times5$ full factorial design: There are 5 levels of imposed breathing and 5 different moments in time. There are two groups (males and females) and a sample size of $n=20$. Additionally data from respiratory frequency (Fresp) in all conditions.

Respiratory frequency has a direct effect on RSA, so I want to include this as a covariate. I.e. each data point of RSA contains information on Fresp.

Apparently, `SPSS` does not allow that since the covariate is implied to be something that is related to the group differences.

The possible approaches I have considered:

1. Standardize the RSA and the Fresp and subtract the standardized score from each other (so that I obtain variability in RSA 'free' of the variability of Fresp) and the perform a mixed anova on these data.
2. Perform a regression of Fresp on RSA within each individual and subject the residuals to a mixed anova.
3. Perform a multilevel regression with dummy variables and Fresp as independent variable.

Are any of the approaches recommended or is there are different approach that someone would propose?